# Using part of date in CAML query

Tags: sharepoint, caml

The title column in my list contains year only. I want to make a view, where I would display only last 3 years.

I'm trying to use CAML query in List definition:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="Year" />
      <Value Type="Number"> ???? </Value>
    </Geq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

I was trying to get something here using `<Today>` element with `Offset` attribute, but without luck - it's not a DateTime value, but only a number.

How to write filtering condition here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's not a datetime value ,it will never work with `<Today>` and `offset` because these elements are internally convert to SQL DateTime value based on the moment the query is run.

You could create a view where you're looking for any entry above 2009 (as of right 2012) but that would require additional minor work each year to adapt.

I would suggest if possible to create a real date only field and work with it (and maybe only display a calculated field based on that value).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do this in two steps:

1. Create a calculated field of type DateTime (without time) using formulas described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx. It will be something like this =DATE(Year-3,0,0)
2. Do a query using this new column. Something like

> ```
> <Geq>
>         <FieldRef Name="YearCalculated" />
>         <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE"><Today /></Value>    
> </Geq>
> ```

Approach with Offset="-1095" may also work, but i think substracting year value in calculated field will work better. Plus you can always make your calculated field invisible on view forms if required.