# SharePoint - How to use <RowLimit> in List Definition

Tags: sharepoint, splist, list-definition

I'm creating a list view - programatically in XML. The title field contains year only (list is some kind of yearly report). [As I learned that it is not so easy to filter this in CAML in `<Where>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085557/using-part-of-date-in-caml-query), 
I would like to be able to display only 3 items with highest year.

**Can I use `<RowLimit>`**, or something similar **in my ListDefinition's `<View>` section?** Coupled with `<OrderBy>`, this would do the trick.

```
<Query>
 <OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='False' />
 </OrderBy>
<Query>
```

Comment: The normal view editor allows sorting and limiting the result count - you can see how it does that.

Comment: Forgot to mention - I'm creating this in VS, in XML

Comment: Maybe you could comment, vote and accept an answer on your previous question? Maybe the solution lies there already. A calculated field to get part of your year sounds easy enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A view schema should look like below and you can change the 3 inside, 
Paged="FALSE" means "row limit is absolute and there is no link to see more items"

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588460(v=office.11).aspx

```
<RowLimit Paged="FALSE">3</RowLimit>

<View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">3</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef  Name="Title" Ascending="False"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
  </View>
```

Comment: After lot of trial-and-error, that's exactly what I decided to go with.

Comment: only in my case RowLimit Paged="False"